# DateTimePicker bootstrap show left site

Tags: bootstrap-4, datepicker

hi iam use  DateTimePicker bootstrap but show right page
iam use bootstrap min.js ver 3.3.1 bootstrap  css ver v3.1.1
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iam use css clas

```
>  .popover {
>         max-width: 100%;
>         -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
>         box-shadow: 0 5px 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
>         z-index: 999999999;
>         right: auto;
>     }
```